# How to show the entered scores in order?

Tags: java, arrays

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Score {
    int num = 0;//students
    int score = 0;//score
    int[] arr = new int[num];

    public int student() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of students");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
            score = arr[i];
            System.out.println(i + 1 + "students socre : " + score);
        }
        return score;
    }

    public void list() {
        int[] arr = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            //arr[i]=score;
            System.out.println(+score);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Score a = new Score();
        a.student();
        a.list();
    }
}
```

If I input 5 students with scores 10, 20, 30, 40, 50,
so I want console to show

> 1 students socre : 10 2 students socre : 20 3 students socre : 30 4
> students socre : 40 5 students socre : 50
>
> and
>
> 10 20 30 40 50

but my code shows

> 1 students socre : 10 2 students socre : 20 3 students socre : 30 4
> students socre : 40 5 students socre : 50
>
> and
>
> 50 50 50 50 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a local variable named `arr` in method `student()` and in method `list()`. A local variable only exists inside the method. This is referred to as variable scope. Refer to [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) which is part of Oracle's java tutorials.

Simply replace the `int[] arr` with `arr` so that you are using the class member `arr`.

Here is your code with my corrections. I have put comments in the code to show which parts I changed.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Score {
    int num = 0;// students
    int score = 0;// score
    int[] arr = new int[num];

    public int student() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of students");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        arr = new int[num]; // CHANGE HERE
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
            score = arr[i];
            System.out.println(i + 1 + "students score : " + score); // CHANGE HERE
        }
        return score;
    }

    public void list() {
//        int[] arr = new int[num]; <- Remove this line.
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            // arr[i]=score;
            System.out.println(arr[i]); // CHANGE HERE
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Score a = new Score();
        a.student();
        a.list();
    }
}
```

Here is the output when I run the above code.

```
Number of students
5
10
1students score : 10
20
2students score : 20
30
3students score : 30
40
4students score : 40
50
5students score : 50
10
20
30
40
50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void list() {
    int[] arr = new int[num];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        //arr[i]=score;
        System.out.println(+score);
    }
}
```

Instead of this you need to write it like this,

```
public void list() {
    int[] arr = new int[num];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]); //Change this line
    }
}
```